# How to extend a single-entry Indian tourist visa?

Tags: india, tourist-visas, visa-extensions, chinese-citizens

My Chinese friend just landed (Saturday, 25/Feb/2017) in India for a short trip. She has a single-entry Indian tourist visa issued on 27/Nov/2016, which will expire on 27/Feb/2017. Only after landing did she notice the expiry date when the airport official in India reminded her to leave by Monday 27th February.

Saturday and Sunday being a government holiday, is it possible to extend the visa on the last date of expiry being in India as a Chinese?

If possible what are the steps to be followed?

Which department should I visit for the extension? What is the process and what will it be possible to do in a single day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your friend is in a tough position: tourist visas cannot be extended while in India. The rare  exceptions are those granted to individuals of Indian origin, or those who encounter an emergency (medical, stolen passport and, in it, the visa needed to exit). Failing to understand that the duration of visa began when it was issued in November is not considered a valid reason.

Your friend can try for a 14-day extension at the [Ministry of Home Affairs](https://mha.gov.in/) in Delhi, 26 Jaisalmer House, Man Singh Rd, 011-23385748 boihq@mha.nic.in

Another alternative is the Foreigners’ Regional Registration Office, Level 2, East Block 8, Sector 1, Rama Krishna Puram, Delhi, 011-26195530 ffrodli@nic.in

While there are [FRRO regional offices](https://boi.gov.in/content/frro-contact-list), it appears much less likely that one would grant an extension.

In preparation, your friend needs to have in hand a photocopy of her passport information page and visa page, a confirmed air ticket, and a passport-size photo.

Comment: We approached FRRO office and they gave exit visa valid for 5 days and she returned safely. Thanks for the FRRO idea.